# get file path of image style as replacement patterns in views

Tags: 7, views, media

i need something like

```
<img attribute1='value' src='sites/default/files/styles/thumbnails/**pic_0**.jpg'>
```

in views.

i have to use rewrite result because i need attribute1. but i have no idea how to get src of image.
`[filename]` is not always same with file path. -for example `[filename]` is pic.jpg but file path is pic_0.jpg- .

and `[uri]` give me http://example.com/sites/default/files/pic_0.jpg  not http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnails/pic_0.jpg.

how can i get pic_0.jpg or http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnails/pic_0.jpg?

Comment: Is this a regular image field you're displaying in your view?  That doesn't typically have [uri] as a replacement token...

Answer (score 0):

You can get file path of image style in view.tpl

**Example:**

```
/**
 * field with image: "field_image"
 * uri:  (image from field_image) File: Path
 */

$style_name = $view->field['field_image']->options['settings']['image_style'];
$thumb_path = image_style_url($style_name, $uri);
```

I didn't wrote how to get $uri because it depends on type of template file. The general idea is to get a file path of image style by using **image_style_url($style_name, $uri)** in view.tpl file.

Comment: Doing logic and loading things in templates is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [Image URL Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module.

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output image url directly.
>
> Most of the code, maybe more than 90%, is just copy from the drupal core. I think it is stable enough.
>
> **Usage**
>
> 1. After install this module,then you add an image field,then you can
>      goto this bundle's manage display page,here at format column,you can
>      choose "Image URL" instead of "Image".
> 2. When you add an image field in your views,then you config the
>      Formatter for this field, here you can choose "Image URL" instead of
>      "Image".
>
> Then you can output image's URL instead of Image itself.